# Jquery - Unable to retrieve dropdown with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this table :

```
 <table id="fla_inf" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="tab_header" colspan="6">Flavors and Additives</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Brand</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Name</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Dropper type</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity Unit</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Add/Remove row</th>
</tr>
<tr class="flavors">
<td>[brand_list]</td>
<td><select id="arome0" class="arome"></td>
<td><select id="dropper0" class="dropper">
<option selected="selected" value="type1">type 1</option>
<option value="type2">type 2-3</option>
</select></td>
<td><select id="qtyunit0" class="qtyunit">
<option value="ml">ml</option>
<option value="drops">drops</option>
<option selected="selected" value="perc">%</option>
</select></td>
<td><input id="quantity0" class="quantity" type="number" /></td>
<td><input class="addline" src="http://spitilab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/add.png" type="image" /><input class="remline" src="http://spitilab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/delete.png" type="image" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to update the dropdown list with id "arome0" when a value is chosen on the first one generated with the shortcode [brand_list].

I need to use Ajax in order to get the children of the brand and fill the "arome0" dropdown list.

I created this jquery code called when the value of my first dropdown changes.

```
//On selected brand, update flavors list
$(document).on('change', "select[id^='marque']", function() {

        var $brandid =  $(this).val();
        var $brand_dd_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var $flav_dd_id = $brand_dd_id.substr($brand_dd_id.length-1);
        $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id).empty();

        //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: '{"parent_id":"' + $brandid + '"","id":"'+ $flav_dd_id +'",action":"brand_children"}',
                success: function(output) {
                    $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id).html(output);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
        }});

});
```

in my functions.php I added this :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');

function GetBrandChildren($parent_id,$id) {
   $children = wp_dropdown_pages(array('id'=>'arome$id','post_type'=>'aromes-type','child_of'=>$parent_id,'echo'=>0));
   return $children;
}
```

but it's not working, I thing there is a problem with the data returned.
any idea ?

thanks

UPDATE :

it's now working, the final problem is the dropdown is not filtered correctly with the parent post id. Maybe i'm not using the wp_dropdown_page correctly.

the updated functions.php :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');

function GetBrandChildren() {
   $parent_id = $_POST['parent_id'];
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   echo wp_dropdown_pages(array("id"=>"arome$id",'post_type'=>'aromes-type','child_of'=>$parent_id,'echo'=>0));
  //ob_clean();
  //echo "working";
  wp_die();
}

// need these two lines to be ale to locate the admin-ajax.php inside jquery
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

the updated JQuery :

```
//On selected brand, update flavors list
$(document).on('change', "select[id^='marque']", function() {

        var $brandid =  $(this).val();
        var $brand_dd_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var $flav_dd_id = $brand_dd_id.substr($brand_dd_id.length-1);
        $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id).empty();

        //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
        //var ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
        $.ajax({
                url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                        'parent_id': $brandid,
                        'id': $flav_dd_id,
                        'action': 'brand_children'
                      },
                success: function(output) {
                    console.log(output);
                    $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id).html(output);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
        }});

});
```

the last problem is the wp_dropdown_pages is not filtering with the parent id, maybe i'm not using it correctly.

Comment: You can see a lot of what is happening by going to the developer console in your browser.  Specifically, you can see the network calls and responses to see what the page is sending to the server and what data/information the server is sending back

Comment: (array('id'=>'arome$id' is wrong you're not escaping string properly try (array("id"=>"arome$id"

Comment: I made the changes for the 'id' but it still doesn't work. When I look in the console I see the call to admin-ajax.php with a 200 return code, what else can I look at ?

Comment: That ajax request is all types of wrong. No url, hand built json, get request passing json ...

Comment: what exactly should be the URL to call a function defined in functions.php

Comment: did you add $_GET['parent_id'] = $parent_id and $_GET['id'] = $id before using $parent_id and $id in your function???

Comment: I made the modifications, still one problem remains. I changed the type to POST and added the variables from POST data into the function.

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have any elements with 'marque' in the id, so, your ajax call won't ever fire.  Also, what does this do? admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); it's not defined anywhere, so that won't work either.

Comment: the OP stated [brand_list] is a short code. Which means the 'marque' is coming form that short code

Comment: nook is right, the marque id is from the brand_list shortcode. Thanks anyway